# RAMPS PLUS 2 and E1 socket problem (K200 Delta, but related to the PCB , not printer)

Tags: ramps-1.4, delta, thermistor

Total 3D printing newbie here, apologies in advance if my terminology is wrong.

I have a dual head K200 delta printer with a heated bed which I put together 8 months ago, but gave up due to frustration of the following error in Repetier:

```
temp sensor defect marked defect
Error:Printer set into dry run mode until restart!
```

I've tried again today, and all 3 thermistors (and the spare) work fine, but socket E1 on the BT7200 V1.8.26 RAMPS PLUS 2 is giving me -20 °C readings no matter which thermistor I put in.

Even though I’ve tried to tell it there’s only *one* extruder (in Printer Settings), the display right at the bottom of Repetier still thinks there’s *two*.

Today I've emailed the seller and the company I bought it *through*, to see if they can help.

In the meantime - is there any way to make Repetier believe that I only have one extruder, or change things so that I can use the heated bed socket for the other extruder instead and just try to make due without the heatbed for now?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Repetier reads configuration from the printer when a connection is established, so as long as it gets info about 2 heads it will display it.

The best approach will be to disable heatbed or hotend directly in the firmware and reflash the printer. You could also swap pins on the board.

When you decide to reflash the firmware, you could check with producer if they have suitable one or use Marlin [(this is a configuration guide)](http://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html).